The intl string context variable "p" was not provided to the string. next-intl 3.11.0
I'm getting The intl string context variable "p" was not provided to the string for every text with html tags.
Text in json:
{
...
"text": "<p>Our company provides expert assistance and support in the following areas:</p><ol><li><p>Consultations on the legal status of migrants:</p><ul><li>Analysis of legal status and possible paths to legalization</li></ul> ... "
...
}

React component:
const section = searchParams.get("section")
const id = searchParams.get("id");
const t = useTranslations(section);

return (
    <>
      <div
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: t.rich(`${section}.${id}.text`, {
                 p: (chunks) => `<p>${chunks}</p>`,
                 strong: (chunks) => `<strong>${chunks}</strong>`,
                 ul: (chunks) => `<ul>${chunks}</ul>`,
                 ol: (chunks) => `<ol>${chunks}</ol>`,
                 li: (chunks) => `<li>${chunks}</li>`,
               }),
             }}
       >
    </>
)

Component renders correctly.
I use next 14 pages dir, react 18.2.0.
Documentation gives the same way to handle tags.
